# DateTime convert from UTC to other timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am using below code to convert date time to america/Chicago but getting wrong converted time.

```
process.env.TZ = "UTC";
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var startTime = (new Date('2016-04-08 17:40:04')).toISOString();s
var newDateTime = moment(startTime);
var newDateTime = newDateTime.tz('America/Chicago').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss a');
console.log(newDateTime); // expected 2016-04-08 12:40:04 PM
                          // getting  2016-04-08 12:04:04 pm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong format string, `MM` means `Month number`, you need to use `mm` - `Minutes`.

```
var newDateTime = newDateTime.tz('America/Chicago').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss a');
```

[Documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for fast reply.